# AngularJS: return promise reject

Tags: angularjs

I'm making a `Factory` in AngularJS which is something like this:

```
if (href) {
    return $http({ method: method, url: item.href });
}
else {
    // needs to return a failed promise
}
```

So, if the condition is true, everything is I need to do is to invoke the `$http` promise, so it means that who is using my factory is expecting a promise. The thing is: if the condition is false, I need to return a rejected promise. Is there a way to do that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Return [`$q.reject()`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q#reject) which is rejected promise object:

```
if (href) {
    return $http({ method: method, url: item.href });
}
else {
    return $q.reject();
}
```

You can also specify a rejection reason, i.e. `$q.reject('Invalid URL')`.

Comment: Note: must inject `$q`